# What does "总价,以分为单位" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm working in a software project and the documentation for some component I need to integrate is only in Chinese. There's a table that has a field named "Amount" and its description is "总价,以分为单位".

Google translate gives me "Total price, divided into units", and some other page says it's something like "Total Price , in minutes".

The problem is that I feel like the part after the comma is important, and neither of them seem like they fit. The "Amount" field is about money.

Comment: The question isn't clear for me……Generally speaking：We hardly use "cent" nowadays in China. And what's more——for a software company, “分” is usually regurded as "分钟"，this is the time unit. And I'm NOT sure whether you are referring the senario of your programming logic or not?

Comment: It was info about a purchased item. One of the fields was "Amount", or the price of the selected item. In the documentation pdf they used that text to describe it.
 At the time I wasn't sure how it worked. With songyuanyao's help, I realized they decided to implement the price field in "cents".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is when [分](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/xs/5206.htm) is used as the unit(单位) of money, it means `cent`, i.e. one hundredth of `元` (the basic monetary unit of China).

> 价值等于某货币单位百分之一的单位 [cent]

So `总价,以分为单位` means `total price in cents`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what it was. And I didn't think about how I had to multiply the prices I got by 100, or it failed. So this is why. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

总价：(Total price）.

以分为单位（Counted by minute）, this means **every minute you should pay xxxx, and how much time you've taken, so the total price is yyyyy**.

PS：This can be also extended like：

The total price is xxxx, counted by (some unit). The "some unit" may be unit of time, unit of weight, unit of others……ect.

Are you calculating how long you will finish that component and how much you can earn from this? If yes, mine is the answer.

Comment: When come to price ,   分 always mean cents . For time units, explicit word 分钟 (minute) or 分秒  (seconds) is  used.

Comment: @mootmoot：Of course I know that, however have you seen any Chinese actually use "Cent"？Now "cent" is far away from our life, and we calculate how much should be paid for every minute in software company……

Comment: I agree that some country use decimal point to eliminate the units "cents" , e.g. $0.33 . But in mandarin, when talk about monetary units, using cents is common sense.

Comment: Sorry SongWei, I had not seen you asked me to clarify my question. See my answer above.